# Gridview is not showing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

This is my code but the gridview is not showing up

**vb**

```
Public Sub GridViewBind()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from Evaluation", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "Evaluation")
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Evaluation")
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.GridViewBind()
    End Sub End Class
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "true"> </asp:GridView> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: ds.Tables("Evaluation") are you getting Rows and Columns here ????

Comment: Yes I have columns but it is not showing in the the gridview.

Comment: @Abigail do you have any records in **Evaluation** table ?

Comment: @Vikash Yes I have records in **Evaluation** table.

Comment: @Abigail Check code with debugger then. this should help. :)

Comment: @Vikash how can I check?

Comment: @Abigail try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee672313.aspx        and     http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd(v=vs.100).aspx